# Telegram bot cant run because of a library error or some problem with code

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot that needs to use a library for language translation and send 7 messages(including videos) in the selected language. However, for some reason the library is not working and the messages are not being sent. Can someone help me fix this code?  Also, I would like to keep the bot running with my computer off, is there a free program/tool that i can use for that?
I tried to fix the code with chatgpt  but it didnt help, may be a problem with the library. I am expecting to fix this without paying for a library to  translatethe 7 messages.can someone help me? please :)

the code:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from googletrans import Translator

# Create a dictionary to store language options and corresponding emojis.
languages = {
    'en': ' English',
    'es': ' Español',
    'es_mx': ' Español (México)',
    'es_es': ' Español (España)',
    'fr': ' Français',
    'de': ' Deutsch',
    'it': ' Italiano',
    'pt': ' Português',
    'ru': ' Русский',
    'zh': ' 中文',
    'ja': ' 日本語',
    'ko': ' 한굵어',
    'ar': ' العربية',
    'tr': ' Türkçe',
    'el': ' Ελληνικά',
    'nl': ' Nederlands',
    'pl': ' Polski',
    'sv': ' Svenska',
    'da': ' Dansk',
    'fi': ' Suomi',
    'no': ' Norsk',
    'hu': ' Magyar',
    'cs': ' Čeština',
    'ro': ' Română',
}

# Initialize the Telegram bot
bot_token = 'x'
updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Define the handler for the /start command to display language selection
def start(update, context):
    keyboard = []
    for code, language in languages.items():
        keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(language, callback_data=code)])
    
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Please select your language:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

# Define a callback function to handle language selection
def language_selection(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    language = query.data
    selected_language = languages.get(language, 'Unknown Language')

    # Use the Google Translate API to translate the selected language
    translator = Translator()
    translated_language = translator.translate(selected_language, dest=language).text

    query.message.reply_text(f"Language set to {selected_language}: {translated_language}")

    # Send the 7 messages
    messages = [
        "1st,
        "2nd",
        "3rd",
        "video_url_1",  # Replace with the URL of your video
        "5th",
        "video_url_2",  # Replace with the URL of your video
        "7th"
    ]

    query.message.reply_text(messages[0])  # Send the first message

# Add handlers to the dispatcher
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
language_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(language_selection)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(language_handler)

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```